# How to catch ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND errors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I was trying to test whether certain file exist using javascript.(don't want to use Ajax). Want to use catch try to handle  ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error. I tried

```
   try{
            img.attr('src', url)
        }catch(err){
            console.log("file"+ url + " doesn't exist");
        }
```

but it doesn't catch up the error.How do I catch ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error?

Comment: Try to set event-callbacks like `onerror`

Comment: onerror attaches an call back function, but it doesn't skip the error message.I'm thinking using try catch to handle error. Any more ideas?

Comment: You cannot use try/catch for asynchronous events. I am not really a javascript expert but I assume the image loading is asynchronous, otherwise it would block your main thread.

Answer (score 1):

<del>Setting the image attribute src isn't going to throw anything based on the results of the file existing or not, it will just simply show the image or not show it.</del>

<del>You might be able to check the size of the image after it's done loading and see if it is 0 width, but this is still just a hack and might only work for images.</del>

Your best bet is jQuery with ajax and use a simple:

```
$.get("/path/to/file", function(data, status) {  
   console.log("File request status: "+status); 
});
```

**EDIT:**

You might want to check the onerror event like in the comment, you could use the html like:

`<img onerror="onerrFunction()">`

or

js: `imgObject.onerror = function(){}`

---

The error you are referring to as 'ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND' I assume you are finding from a browser such as chrome in the developer console like so:

[image: screenshot]

However, this is not a javascript erro being thrown, so you cannot catch it with js code. This is just a browser error to help debug your code. There might be other ways to catch these kinds of errors but as for what you are asking, that probably isn't in the scope of the question.

Comment: I intend to keep the page local so far. onerror attaches an call back function, but it doesn't skip the error message.I'm thinking using try catch to handle error. Any more ideas?

Comment: @ElliscopeFang I just added to my answer what might be helpful

Comment: Chrome destroying my beautiful colored output in console. I have tried everything.. setting `void`, having `( )`, tried `try`. Because `.onerror` is defined and handled correctly it is a Chrome bug - not in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome does it to inform. Even if you handle `onerror` correctly with correct error handling with `try-catch` and every trick with `void` or `( )` that is told to prevent error - **you can not fix it**. It is out of Javascript control.

The best you can do is to let those errors scroll away to the top, to not clutter your output. This works if you also want to remove the clutter of line numbers on each `console.log` to get a clean output with relevant information. Use `\n` as line break. A dashed line separate the errors from your output.

```
var logs = ""

function log(x) {
  logs += '\n\n' + x
}

//your code
try{
  img.attr('src', url)
}catch(err){
  log("file"+ url + " doesn't exist")
}

setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("%c" + logs, "border-top: dashed 2px black;")
}, 1000)
```

Maybe better replace the `setTimeout` with a function called in end of your program.

Comment: is it possible to simple read the output of console.onerror to determine if it happened and parse it?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found is making a fake request to check the file is wherever exist or not like this:

```
  var request;
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
      request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  else
  request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  request.open('GET', url, false);
  request.send();
  // the object request will be actually modified
  if (request.status === 404) {
      console.log("file"+ url + " doesn't exist");
  } 
  else
  {
      img.attr('src', url)
  }
```

Notice: It only works with same origin, so if you need to check the file in other origins. you need to use Ajax or backend languages.